# How do I switch from a service-based company to a product-based companies with 1.5 years of experience?

Tags: career-switch

Honestly very few people are generous enough to refer you to another firm. How do I explain to the outside world that I work in IT but I am good at coding?

Comment: Applying for the job you want might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Make a cookbook application](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/111883/1996) with programming languages and a stack of your choice.
2. Check in your code to GitHub or Bitbucket with a Readme.txt.
3. Be prepared to explain how you created the cookbook application.
4. Go find recruiters who are recruiting for jobs that require familiarity with the programming languages and stack of your choice.

P.S. #3 is key because your ability to gain employment will be largely based on how well you can articulate how you created the cookbook application. Of course, you can only do this well if you created a fully functional cookbook application.

Answer (score 1):

Look for vacancies for the kind of jobs you want and see if the skills and experience needed fit your own.

Since you don't have any experience in coding, you might want to try and get yourself a recognized qualification and go from there.